# Silent install of SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I write a program and I want to create an installation file that install my app and SQL Server 2014 Express with my instance name and install .net 3.5 in silent mode.

I'm trying to make my installation file with "Advanced installer" and "Installshield", but I can not install that silently.

If you know how I can do that, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to install services silently? There might be special files or services that can interact with your service that I can resolve if you'd only let me.

Comment: It'd help to see the error you're getting. The question is simple: yes you can. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017) you have all the information you need. As for .NET Framework, you can use Installshield or any other packager software and include it as a pre-requisite.

Comment: @DourHighArch Our customers are not educated and we should to install app with one click . if i can generate a installation file that install all files with one click, we do not need much support

Comment: It sounds like you have a typical end-user desktop app, and want Sql Server just as a local data store. Sql Server is actually a _very poor choice_ here. It's a **server** engine, and wants to run like a server, where it uses resources all the time, and as many as it can. You'll do much better wtih an _in-process_ engine, like sqlite, sql server compact, vistadb, or even ms access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you're answer.
I can do this with [Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017#Install).
I use advance installer and
I put SQL Server in Pre-install at Prerequisites and write in Install Command Lines

```
/q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /UpdateEnabled=False /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=Trv_Trv
```

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hScYC.png)

if you want to show progress bar you should write /qs instead of /q
if you wand to use SQL authentication you should use /SECURITYMODE=SQL and write passworl like /SAPWD=[You're password]